# How to access StaticRouter's 'context' prop within a Context Provider

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-context

I am working on a server-side rendered implementation for React's Context API, and when wrapping a StaticRouter around my Provider, like so:

```
<StaticRouter location={req.path} context={{users: data}}>
  <UserProvider>
    {renderRoutes(Routes)}
  </UserProvider>
</StaticRouter>
```

I am unable to access the 'staticContext' property from within my Provider component.

```
class UserProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    /* HERE */
    let users = isBrowser ? window.CONTEXT_VALUE 
    : this.props.staticContext.users;

    this.state = {
      users,
      getUsers: () => {},
      addUser: (user) => {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

The stack is giving me the error: "cannot read property 'users' of undefined"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/StaticRouter/context-object), only the routes that are declared within the usual 'Routes' `Object[]` are able to access the `staticContext` prop, not every component that the `StaticRouter` is wrapping.

Comment: Thank you man ! I have read all docs but still haven't understood this moment.